# Parent Page refresh on user response in Microsoft BOT dotnet

Tags: c#, asp.net, botframework

I used a webchat channel in a default.aspx, I created a bot with DotNet to redirect to the user requested pages.

Can we have a feature like Response.Redirect in the framework? If user sends input as a "Home", can i redirect page to "home.aspx" from "default.aspx" directly?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: If you would like to request a feature you can do so [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/new)

Comment: Thanks, Jason. I requested the feature in the mentioned link.